# Can I use Switch with an inequality?

Tags: programming, core-language

I'd like to have something like:

```
Switch[x,
  10, a = 3; b = 7,
  >10, a = 5; c = 6,
  _, a = 7; d = 12, b = 1];
```

I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: `Switch` takes patterns.  You want a pattern like `x_ /; x > 10`.

Comment: The function you are looking for is [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html)

Comment: @2012rcampion - I can't figure out how to use that pattern in Switch.  Can you give me a short example?

Comment: `Switch[x, 10, a = 3; b = 7, x_ /; x > 10, a = 5; c = 6, _, a = 7; d = 12, b = 1]`: Use it like any other pattern.

Comment: I appreciate the help - it gets me what I needed - thanks!  Putting it on hold seems kind of harsh.  I see that I have a typo in my example with ",b=1".  Not really relevant to the problem.  The ">10" in the example was to demonstrate what I was trying to accomplish - I knew that it was not correct.  As far as being easy to find in the documentation, I looked for quite a while.  It didn't seem easy to me.  Clearly I didn't know how to use a pattern for this.  I've used them for arguments, and rules.  I now know how to use a pattern in this context.  Thanks again for the help, but ouch!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with `Switch`, but that would be an awkward application of `Switch`.

```
Clear[a, b, c, d];
With[{x = 42},
  Switch[x,
    _?(# == 10 &), a = 3; b = 7; "==10",
    _?(# > 10 &), a = 5; c = 6; ">10",
    _, a = 7; d = 12; b = 1; "Otherwise"]]
```

> ```
> ">10"
> ```

```
 {a, b, c, d}
```

> ```
> {5, b, 6, d}
> ```

However, `Which` is a better choice

```
Clear[a, b, c, d];
With[{x = 42},
  Which[
    x == 10, a = 3; b = 7; "==10",
    x > 10, a = 5; c = 6; ">10",
    True, a = 7; d = 12; b = 1; "Otherwise"]]
```

> ```
> ">10"
> ```

```
 {a, b, c, d}
```

> ```
> {5, b, 6, d}
> ```